# Cannot install any package using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda

Whenever I tried to install a package via `pip install <package>` from my Amazon EC2 instance, I have the following problem:

```
pip install opencv-python
Collecting opencv-python
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('rsa routines', 'INT_RSA_VERIFY', 'bad signature'), ('asn1 encoding routines', 'ASN1_item_verify', 'EVP lib'), ('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),)': /simple/opencv-python/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('rsa routines', 'INT_RSA_VERIFY', 'bad signature'), ('asn1 encoding routines', 'ASN1_item_verify', 'EVP lib'), ('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),)': /simple/opencv-python/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('rsa routines', 'INT_RSA_VERIFY', 'bad signature'), ('asn1 encoding routines', 'ASN1_item_verify', 'EVP lib'), ('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),)': /simple/opencv-python/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('rsa routines', 'INT_RSA_VERIFY', 'bad signature'), ('asn1 encoding routines', 'ASN1_item_verify', 'EVP lib'), ('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),)': /simple/opencv-python/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('rsa routines', 'INT_RSA_VERIFY', 'bad signature'), ('asn1 encoding routines', 'ASN1_item_verify', 'EVP lib'), ('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),)': /simple/opencv-python/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/opencv-python/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/opencv-python/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('rsa routines', 'INT_RSA_VERIFY', 'bad signature'), ('asn1 encoding routines', 'ASN1_item_verify', 'EVP lib'), ('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),)) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for opencv-python
```

In the example above, the package `opencv-python` is available at `https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/`. I'm using Python 3.6 from an Anaconda environment.

Furthermore, using `conda install <package>` results in the same error:

```
conda search numpy
Loading channels: failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/free/noarch/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([(\'SSL routines\', \'tls_process_key_exchange\', \'bad signature\')],)",),))',),)
```

I don't know if it's a problem with the network interface or with the Python environment? I've tried all solutions I found, nothing worked.

Comment: Can you connect to any network resource at all?

Comment: Yes, I tried `wget` an image, and it works.

Comment: What about https resources?

Comment: `pip install` worked for me. Currently downloading 39.7 mb of opencv-python 4.0.0.21.

Comment: @Yossi `wget` not working for `https`, probably it's the network setting, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that if you reviewed your VPC settings, you will find that you are blocking external IP addresses using a Network ACLS. Generally these are used for controlling traffic between subnets in your VPC.

It's a Common Mistake on Amazon EC2.

Reviewing Your Settings will fix the Problem!

Regards,

P.S. Your Python Environment Works Fine!

Comment: Probably yes because `wget` is not working for https resources. I'll check and confirm

Answer (score 2):

Please verify that your instance's security group allows outbound traffic to port 443

Answer (score 0):

Try to `Network Reset` option in Windows 10

- Options
- Network & Internet
- Status tab
- Look the end of page (Network Reset)
- Reset Now

> It'll delete all of saved WI-FI password

Answer (score 0):

**This is a windows specific answer**  for anyone facing the same problem as described in the question, but on a windows machine. As of now there is no answer addressing this issue for Windows OS on StackOverflow.

I found this after days of searching!

Step 1: Press Win+R to open Run, type in “regedit” and click OK.
Step 2: Move to HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Windows/Current Version/Internet Settings.
Step 3: Find a file with the name 'ProxyServer' and delete it.
Step 4: Open cmd 
Step 5: Fire a command 'pip install flask-bcrypt'

Credits: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7424